# Using IUP with C on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, gcc, ubuntu-12.04, iup

Somebody please help me to develop apps with  IUP Portable User Interface toolkit with C in Linux (Ubuntu 12.04_amd64(actually i am using elementary :P) with Linux 3.2.0-51-generic to be more specific)[by the way i know nothing about iup - i came across it just 24 hrs ago and failed to run even the helloworld example :(]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many reasons an application would fail to build. Without knowing what exactly happen makes it more difficult to help.

If you contact the IUP team at iup@tecgraf.puc-rio.br or post a message at the IUP mailing list I would be glad to assist you.

Best,
Antonio Scuri